# how to write a sequence of packets to a Node.js net.Socket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, promise

Would like to know if there's anything special i need to do to write an array of packets, sequentially to an instance of `net.Socket` in Node.js.

I'm not sure if writing to the same socket in a `for` loop would be synchronous or also async.

If it's async, would i have to promisify `Socket.write` and have the loop set up a `.then()` chain. I'm already using `bluebird` for promises.

thanks!

Comment: If by "async" you mean "does it block I/O" then yes, `for` loops block on execution. Look into an async library like https://github.com/caolan/async to work with the array.

Comment: the question isn't really about weather `for` loops block (they don't). it's whether `Socket.write()` blocks follow-up writes to the same socket. i would assume it has a way of doing this since you cannot write to a single socket multiple packets simultaneously.

Comment: `for` loops absolutely DO block. Execution of the script doesn't continue until the for loop ends and therefore ties up the thread.

Comment: you're right, but if everything in the `for` loop returns asynchronously, it won't block for longer than it takes to just execute the code in the loop. which can in the microseconds. if your whole loop is something like setting up a promise on each iteration. what i'd like to know is if i call `mysocket.write(packets[i], encoding, callback)` if they are guaranteed to execute in order and map the requestPacket:responseData 1:1 for the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by this.  Most Node.js examples make it seem like `write()` is synchronous:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.write('Hello!');
  socket.end();
});
```

It turns out the non-callback version of `write()` actually means `write_eventually()`.  If it can't actually write your data to the socket, it queues it up in memory.  Node takes care of writing the queued data out to the socket eventually.

I imagine they did this because callbacks are annoying and this reduces the number of callbacks in your code.  The downside is that it uses more memory (see: [`Socket.bufferSize`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_buffersize])).

If you're pushing lots of data, it's more memory-efficient to use the callback version of `write()`:

```
"use strict";

var net = require("net")

function writeArray(arrayOfChunks, socket, callback) {
  var i = 0;
  function f() {
    if (i >= arrayOfChunks.length) {
      callback();
    } else {
      socket.write(arrayOfChunks[i++], null, f);
    }
  }
  f()
}

var server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  var arrayOfChunks = ['Hello', ', ', 'world!', '\n'];
  writeArray(arrayOfChunks, socket, () => {
    socket.write('DONE\n', null, () => {
      socket.end();
    })
  })
})

server.listen(9191, () => {
  console.log("Server listening.");
})
```

But it's 2016, so maybe you can just use `async`/`await` and not have to deal with callback/promise nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple writes are guaranteed to be executed in order.

Requests:Responses are not guaranteed to be mapped 1:1.